# Javascript Class Definition with Array Member

Tags: javascript, java, arrays, class, object

I wrote the code in Java, no problem. Here I am giving the Java code:

```
public class CarGallery {

    static int carCounter=10;
    static Gallery[] car = new Gallery[carCounter]; 

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    car[0].weight = (float) 1.25;
    car[0].weight = (float) 0.87;
    // ... and so on ... // 
    }   
}

 class Gallery {

    public float weight;
    public float height;
    public int colorCode;
    public int stockGallery;
};
```

The thing is, I want to write the same code in Javascript. Here is the code that does not work:

```
var cars = {weight:0 , height:0 , stock:0 , model:"..."};
var cars = new Array();

cars[0].weight=1.2;
cars[0].height=0.87;
cars[0].stock=2;
cars[0].model="320";
```

- I read some documents and saw that there is no class definition in Javascript like Java classes.
- I found class definition in JS with constructors, but **I don't want to use constructors.**
- The member should be defined as array like:

  static Gallery[] car = new Gallery[carCounter];

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JavaScript equivalent to your Java would be.

```
function Gallery() {
  this.weight = null;
  this.height = null;
  this.colorCode = null;
  this.stockGallery = null;
};

var carCounter = 10;
var carGallery = new Array(carCounter);

carGallery[0] = new Gallery();
carGallery[0].weight = 1.2;
carGallery[0].height = 0.87;
carGallery[0].colorCode = 2
carGallery[0].stockGallery = 3;

carGallery[1] = new Gallery();
carGallery[1].weight = 2.2;
...
```

Comment: Thank you jordanwillis, it works without any problem! :)